# Duplicate records with postgres

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql

Hello everyone Im working with postgres to get a result pair but I am getting duplicate records.
Im getting something like:

```
stop_name|departure_time
------------------------
AAA      | 16489646
BBB      | 16465464
AAA      | 46546665
AAA      | 18421654
BBB      | 16849685
AAA      | 56496865
```

I expect something like:

```
stop_name|departure_time
------------------------
AAA      | 16489646
BBB      | 16465464
```

Because is a bit complex I made a fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/27eaf/1) where you can see a sample of the schema and the query Im using. Can some one gimme a hand to achieve the expected results? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: This work is related to GTFS(transportation) and I want to get the possible departures given a specific time. After some discussion at work the answer given will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use the `MIN` aggregate:

```
SELECT s.stop_name, min(st.departure_time) departure_time
  FROM stops s
    INNER JOIN stop_times st
      ON s.stop_id = st.stop_id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT t.trip_id, t.route_id
        FROM trips t, northbound nb
        WHERE t.trip_id LIKE CONCAT(nb.train_id,'%')
        AND t.route_id = '2'
    ) TR
      ON TR.trip_id = st.trip_id
WHERE st.departure_time > 1373948273
GROUP BY s.stop_name
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/27eaf/4)

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes you get wrapped up with complexity and forget the simple things. That was the case here :(